# Why is my code coming up with the 'expected a character buffer object' python error when i try and write a file?

Tags: python

I have been trying to write my attributes into a file like so:

```
def player1():
        name1=raw_input("what would you like to call the first player?")
        diceroll()
        print name1,"has:"
        time.sleep(1)
        z = strength()
        time.sleep(1)
        x = skill()
        f = open('attributes.txt','w+')
        f.write(name1)
        f.write("has")
        f.write(x)
        f.write("strength and")
        f.write(z)
        f.write("skill")
```

However when I come to run my code it come up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\GCSE\Computing\Programming\shorterversion.py", line 83, in <module>
    loop()
  File "H:\GCSE\Computing\Programming\shorterversion.py", line 77, in loop
    player1()
  File "H:\GCSE\Computing\Programming\shorterversion.py", line 37, in player1
    f.write(x)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

How do I fix this? here is my entire code:

```
import random
import time
def loop():
    global lol
    def intro():
        print "welcome to an attribute simulator game!"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "Today we will be calculating the strength and skill of virtual characters!"

    def strength():
        dice12 = random.randint(1,12)
        dice04 = random.randint(1,4)
        strfinalstats = dice12/dice04+10
        print ">",strfinalstats,"strength"

    def skill():
        dice12 = random.randint(1,12)
        dice04 = random.randint(1,4)
        skfinalstats = dice12/dice04+10
        print ">",skfinalstats,"skill!"

    def diceroll():
        print ("The dice of fate are being rolled!!")

    def player1():
        name1=raw_input("what would you like to call the first player?")
        diceroll()
        print name1,"has:"
        time.sleep(1)
        z = strength()
        time.sleep(1)
        x = skill()
        f = open('attributes.txt','w+')
        f.write(name1)
        f.write("has")
        f.write(x)
        f.write("strength and")
        f.write(z)
        f.write("skill")

    def player2():
        name2=raw_input("what would you like to call the first player?")
        diceroll()
        print name2,"has:"
        time.sleep(1)
        strength()
        time.sleep(1)
        skill()
        f = open('attributes.txt','w+')
        f.write(name2)
        f.write("has")
        f.write(x)
        f.write("strength and")
        f.write(z)
        f.write("skill")


    def player3():
        name3=raw_input("what would you like to call the first player?")
        diceroll()
        print name3,"has:"
        time.sleep(1)
        strength()
        time.sleep(1)
        skill()
        f = open('attributes.txt','w+')
        f.write(name3)
        f.write("has")
        f.write(x)
        f.write("strength and")
        f.write(z)
        f.write("skill")

    intro()
    time.sleep(1)
    player1()
    player2()
    player3()
    lol=raw_input("would you like to run the program again? Say yes or press any letter/number key to exit!")
repeat = True
while repeat==True:
    loop()
    time.sleep(1)
    if lol=="yes":
        print "ok lets start again!"
        repeat = True
    else:
        print "thankyou for playing!"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "exiting..."
        exit()
```

Comment: It looks like you could really gain a lot by looking into [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)!

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about the difference between printing something and returning it.  Your function here:

```
def skill():
    dice12 = random.randint(1,12)
    dice04 = random.randint(1,4)
    skfinalstats = dice12/dice04+10
    print ">",skfinalstats,"skill!"
```

...doesn't explicitly return anything, which is the same as returning `None`.

The error you receive is exactly what you get if you attempt to write `None` into a file:

```
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'wt')
>>> f.write(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
>>>
```

Change the skill() function to something like:

```
def skill():
    dice12 = random.randint(1,12)
    dice04 = random.randint(1,4)
    skfinalstats = dice12/dice04+10
    return  "> {} skill!".format(skfinalstats)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is expecting a string object, however you are providing whatever the output of the `strength()` function is.  Since your function lacks a `return`statement, this will be the `NoneType`

You need to modify your functions to have a `return` statement, which I suspect you want to look like this:

```
def strength():
    dice12 = random.randint(1,12)
    dice04 = random.randint(1,4)
    strfinalstats = dice12/dice04+10
    print ">",strfinalstats,"strength"
    return strfinalstats
```

As an aside, when you write to the file, you could make use of the [`str.format()` functio](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)n to make it a little nicer:

```
f.write("{} has {} strength and {} skill".format(name1, x, y))
```